Multiplicity of irreducible characters inside symmetric powers of a faithful character
Let $ G $ be a finite group of order $ n $. Let $ f $ be a faithful representation of $ G $ and by abuse of notation let $ f $ also denote the corresponding character. It is my experience that for each irreducible character $ \chi $ of $ G $ there is a sort of periodicity $ d_\chi $ such that
$$
\langle Sym^{k+n}(f),\chi \rangle=d_\chi+\langle Sym^k(f),\chi \rangle
$$
For example I noticed this for the groups $ SL(2,3) $ and $ SL(2,5) $.
Does someone have a reference, proof, or better description of this periodicity phenomenon for the multiplicity of an irrep inside symmetric tensor powers of a faithful rep? Is there a direct way to determine the periodicity $ d_\chi $ from information about $ G $ and $ \chi $?

The result does not hold if $G={1}$. Consider $f=\chi=1_G$.

@Deif ok I rephrased the statement to accommodate that example

The answer to your question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4551620/faithful-representations-and-small-tensor-powers has an expression for the generating function of $\langle f^k,\chi\rangle$ - does that not give info?

@ancientmathematician ah my mistake the examples I'm familiar with are not for the tensor power but rather for the symmetric tensor power, I have edited my post accordingly

My intuition is this should only work for $f$ of dimension $2$. Do you have any examples of this working with a faithful representation of dimension greater than $2$?

@Nate you got me! my motivating examples are all for $ f $ of dimension 2, how did you know? where is your (probably correct) intuition coming from?

Well your formula suggests $\langle Sym^k(f), \chi \rangle$ grows linearly with $k$, or I guess linearly on each congruence class mod n.  But $\dim(Sym^k(f))$ grows polynomially in $k$ with degree $dim(f) -1$, so the only way it is linear is if $dim(f) = 2$.

If $\chi $ is the trivial character, Molien's theorem from invariant theory gives a formula for $\langle Sym^k(f), \chi \rangle$.  From that it indeed follows that it ends up being a PORC (polynomial on residue classes) function in $k$. Probably there is a variation for other characters too.

@Nate Isn't $\langle \psi,\chi\rangle=\langle \psi\otimes\bar{\chi},1\rangle$ so one can apply Molien. (I think the formula I referenced in the earlier question/answer is just Molien.)

@ancientmathematician Ahh right, nice trick.
